# How can I debug an Outlook App running in Desktop

Tags: javascript, debugging, office-addins

I've been working on an Outlook Add-in, which is now working fine as a prototype in Outlook Web App and indeed works - usually - in Desktop too; but I find sometimes the App freezes in Desktop (not in the Web App) but I can't find how to debug the Desktop; none of the given Microsoft options seem to apply - am I missing something?

Tech note: I've tried Microsoft Edge DevTools, but it can't see the app to attach to it; I'm thinking that might be because the Outlook Add-in only runs momentarily …?

Comment: Is it that you can't figure out how to run your addin in the desktop client? Or just need to know how to connect debugging tools to the addin running in the desktop client?

Comment: The latter Markdon, I can't find a way to connect debugging tools to the Add-In in Desktop Client; in fact, I can't even find a way to see Console output; must be missing something

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Microsoft's docs for how to test and debug addins.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/test-debug-office-add-ins)

Comment: Thanks for link, but have looked at it, but - so far - not able to get debug to work; two specific issues 1) Edge DevTools can't see Outlook, neither the desktop nor web version of Outlook, despite following [MS guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10) 2) Even when running within Visual Studio, using IIS, I can't find the console log output. Any pointers appreciated